# Sort array in array & delete by matching elements

Tags: ruby

I have parsed an excel to an array of arrays. New names are added to the bottom of the excel and some of them may already exist. So I'd like to firstly sort the array which is working.
Then I'd like to remove any duplicates based on matching the first two elements (and the third if it's not null). The array that stays is the one that does not have a null fourth element.

```
array  = []
sorted = []

array << ["John", "Smith", "null"] + [ "null", "null", "y", "y", "n", "n",   "n"]
array << ["Mary", "Jones","mary@addy.com,"  "fsgdseg", "comment", "y", "y", "n", "n", "n"]
array << ["Peter", "Ross", "null", "adfgehs", "comment", "y", "y", "n", "n", "n"]
array << ["John", "Smith", "john@smith.com", "dfsgfsdgsd", "comment", "y", "y", "n", "n", "n"]

array.sort_by {|e| [e[0], e[3]]} .each {|line| sorted << line }

sorted.each{ |i| p i}

#=> ["John", "Smith", "john@smith.com", "dfsgfsdgsd", "comment", "y", "y", "n", "n", "n"]
#=> ["John", "Smith", "null", "null", "null", "y", "y", "n", "n", "n"]
#=> ["Mary", "Jones", "mary@addy.com,fsgdseg", "comment", "y", "y", "n", "n", "n"]
#=> ["Peter", "Ross", "null", "adfgehs", "comment", "y", "y", "n", "n", "n"]
```

Now I'd like to delete arrays whose elements 0, 1 match & 2(if there) & delete the one whose element 3 is not null.

Comment: OP wants to delete the array which has elements where 0,1,2 index elements of array match with respective elements of another array...ideally removal of duplicate arrays.

Comment: Can you define what the two fields after emails are?

Comment: They will be unique user identifiers (lower case single word alphanumeric)

Comment: @VamsiKrishna removal of which? 1st and 4th arrays share same 0th and 1st values. which one will be deleted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe i don't understand the question but maybe this is what you whant.

So Maybe this ?

```
array, sorted = [], []

array << ["John", "Smith", "null"] + [ "null", "null", "y", "y", "n", "n",   "n"]
array << ["Mary", "Jones","mary@addy.com,"  "fsgdseg", "comment", "y", "y", "n", "n", "n"]
array << ["Peter", "Ross", "null", "adfgehs", "comment", "y", "y", "n", "n", "n"]
array << ["John", "Smith", "john@smith.com", "dfsgfsdgsd", "comment", "y", "y", "n", "n", "n"]

is_define = {}
array.sort_by {|e| [e[0], e[3]]} .each {|line|
  unless line[3].to_s == "null"
    full_name_a = line[0..1]

    if is_define.has_key?(full_name_a)
      unless is_define[full_name_a].include?(line[3])
        is_define[full_name_a] << line[3]
        sorted << line
      end
    else
      is_define[full_name_a] = [line[3]]
      sorted << line
    end
  end
}
sorted.each do |a| p a end

# => ["John", "Smith", "john@smith.com", "dfsgfsdgsd", "comment", "y", "y", "n", "n", "n"]
# => ["Mary", "Jones", "mary@addy.com,fsgdseg", "comment", "y", "y", "n", "n", "n"]
# => ["Peter", "Ross", "null", "adfgehs", "comment", "y", "y", "n", "n", "n"]
```

I have result, so i update source code.

Comment: It's actually the opposite of your result that I want. 
`# => [["John", "Smith", "null", "null", "null", "y", "y", "n", "n", "n"]]` 

should be removed and the others should remain.

Comment: Yes, that's it. Glad you understood. There are some neat uses of methods was not aware of. Thanks.

Comment: @davidt It was my pleasure to help

Answer (score 4):

**Interpretation of question**

I have assumed that the question is as follows. Arrays (elements of an array) are to be grouped. Two arrays are in the same group if the first three elements of each array are the same or if the first two elements are the same and the third element equals "null" for one or both arrays. If a group consists of a single array, the group is to be replaced by that array. If a group contains two or more arrays, the fourth element of exactly one of those arrays will not be "null", and the group is to be replaced by that array..

If this interpretation is not correct, it should not be difficult to modify the code below to conform with the correct interpretation.

**Code**

```
def select_arrays(array)
  h = array.group_by { |a| a[0,3] }
  keys = h.keys
  h.each_key do |k|
    next unless k[2]=="null"
    key = keys.find { |kk| (k!=kk) &&  k[0,2]==kk[0,2] }
    h[key].concat(h.delete(k)) if key
  end.values.map { |a|
     (a.size==1) ? a.first : a.find { |e| e[3] != "null"} }.sort
end
```

**Example**

```
array = [
  ["John", "Smith", "null", "null", "null", "y", "y", "n", "n", "n"],
  ["Peter", "Ross", "null", "adfgehs", "comment", "y", "y", "n", "n", "n"],
  ["Mary", "Jones", "mary@addy.com", "fsgdseg", "comment", "y", "y", "n", "n", "n"],
  ["John", "Smith", "john@smith.com", "dfsgfsdgsd", "comment", "y", "y", "n", "n", "n"],
  ["Peter", "Ross", "Bubba", "null", "comment", "y", "y", "n", "n", "n"],
  ["John", "Smith", "john@smith.com", "null", "comment", "y", "y", "n", "n", "n"]
]

select_arrays(array)
  #=> [["John", "Smith", "john@smith.com", "dfsgfsdgsd",
  #       "comment", "y", "y", "n", "n", "n"],
  #    ["Mary", "Jones", "mary@addy.com", "fsgdseg",
  #      "comment", "y", "y", "n", "n", "n"],
  #    ["Peter", "Ross", "null", "adfgehs",
  #       "comment", "y", "y", "n", "n", "n"]]
```

**Explanation**

The steps are:

- Group the arrays by the first three elements, using [Enumerable#group_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by), which produces a hash, the keys being three element arrays, the values being an array of arrays whose first three elements that match the key.
- For each key for which the third element is "null", see if there is another key that matches on the first two elements. If there is, concatenate the value of the found key with the value of the first key and delete the key-value pair for the first key. This will reduce the hash to having no pair of keys whose first two elements are the same.
- Extract the values from the hash, into an array `x` of arrays.
- Convert each element of `x` (an array) to a single array. If the element `y` has only one element, convert to `y.first`; else select the element `arr` of `y` for which `arr[2] != "null"`.
- If desired, sort the resulting array.

For `array` above, we compute:

```
h = array.group_by { |a| a[0,3] }
  #=> {["John", "Smith", "null"]=>
  #      [["John", "Smith", "null", "null",
  #          "null", "y", "y", "n", "n", "n"]],
  #    ["Peter", "Ross", "null"]=>
  #      [["Peter", "Ross", "null", "adfgehs",
  #          "comment", "y", "y", "n", "n", "n"]],
  #    ["Mary", "Jones", "mary@addy.com"]=>
  #      [["Mary", "Jones", "mary@addy.com", "fsgdseg",
  #          "comment", "y", "y", "n", "n", "n"]],
  #    ["John", "Smith", "john@smith.com"]=>
  #      [["John", "Smith", "john@smith.com", "dfsgfsdgsd",
  #          "comment", "y", "y", "n", "n", "n"],
  #       ["John", "Smith", "john@smith.com", "null",
  #          "comment", "y", "y", "n", "n", "n"]],
  #    ["Peter", "Ross", "Bubba"]=>
  #      [["Peter", "Ross", "Bubba", "null",
  #          "comment", "y", "y", "n", "n", "n"]]} 

keys = h.keys
  #=> [["John", "Smith", "null"],
  #    ["Peter", "Ross", "null"],
  #    ["Mary", "Jones", "mary@addy.com"],
  #    ["John", "Smith", "john@smith.com"],
  #    ["Peter", "Ross", "Bubba"]] 

enum = h.each_key
  #=> #<Enumerator: {["John", "Smith", "null"]=>[["John", "Smith",...
  #   ...}:each_key>
```

Each element of the enumerator is passed to the block by [Hash#each](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-i-each) and assigned to the block variable `k`. We can simulate this by using [Enumerator#next](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Enumerator.html#method-i-next):

```
k = enum.next
  #=> ["John", "Smith", "null"] 

next unless k[2]=="null"
```

As `k[2] == "null"`, we don't go to the end of the loop.

```
key = keys.find { |kk| (k!=kk) &&  k[0,2]==kk[0,2] }
  #=> ["John", "Smith", "john@smith.com"]
```

We found a different key that matches on the first two elements, so we add `h[k]` to `h[key]` and delete the key `k`:

```
h[key].concat(h.delete(k)) if key
  #=> [["John", "Smith", "john@smith.com", "dfsgfsdgsd",
  #       "comment", "y", "y", "n", "n", "n"],
  #    ["John", "Smith", "john@smith.com", "null",
  #       "comment", "y", "y", "n", "n", "n"],
  #    ["John", "Smith", "null", "null",
  #        "null", "y", "y", "n", "n", "n"]]
```

Let's confirm that one key has been deleted:

```
h.each_key.to_a
  #=> [["Peter", "Ross", "null"],
  #    ["Mary", "Jones", "mary@addy.com"],
  #    ["John", "Smith", "john@smith.com"],
  #    ["Peter", "Ross", "Bubba"]]
```

Now pass the next element of `enum` into the block:

```
k = enum.next
  #=> ["Peter", "Ross", "null"] 
next unless k[2]=="null"
key = keys.find { |kk| (k!=kk) &&  k[0,2]==kk[0,2] }
  #=> ["Peter", "Ross", "Bubba"] 
h[key].concat(h.delete(k)) if key
```

So now:

```
h  #=> {["Mary", "Jones", "mary@addy.com"]=>
   #      [["Mary", "Jones", "mary@addy.com", "fsgdseg",
   #          "comment", "y", "y", "n", "n", "n"]],
   #    ["John", "Smith", "john@smith.com"]=>
   #      [["John", "Smith", "john@smith.com", "dfsgfsdgsd",
   #          "comment", "y", "y", "n", "n", "n"],
   #       ["John", "Smith", "john@smith.com", "null",
   #          "comment", "y", "y", "n", "n", "n"],
   #       ["John", "Smith", "null", "null",
   #          "null", "y", "y", "n", "n", "n"]],
   #    ["Peter", "Ross", "Bubba"]=>
   #      [["Peter", "Ross", "Bubba", "null",
   #          "comment", "y", "y", "n", "n", "n"],
   #       ["Peter", "Ross", "null", "adfgehs",
   #          "comment", "y", "y", "n", "n", "n"]]}
```

No more changes to `h` are made as we process the remaining elements of `enum` because `k[2] != "null"` for all those values.

Now extract the values of `h`:

```
v = h.values
  #=> [[["Mary", "Jones", "mary@addy.com", "fsgdseg",
  #        "comment", "y", "y", "n", "n", "n"]],
  #    [["John", "Smith", "john@smith.com", "dfsgfsdgsd",
  #        "comment", "y", "y", "n", "n", "n"],
  #     ["John", "Smith", "john@smith.com", "null",
  #        "comment", "y", "y", "n", "n", "n"],
  #     ["John", "Smith", "null", "null",
  #        "null", "y", "y", "n", "n", "n"]],
  #    [["Peter", "Ross", "Bubba", "null",
  #        "comment", "y", "y", "n", "n", "n"],
  #     ["Peter", "Ross", "null", "adfgehs",
  #        "comment", "y", "y", "n", "n", "n"]]]
```

Now go through the values. If a value contains a single element, replace the array by that element; else replace the array by the element `a` for which `a[3] != "null"`:

```
arr = v.map { |a| (a.size==1) ? a.first : a.find { |e| e[3] != "null"} }
  #=> [["Mary", "Jones", "mary@addy.com", "fsgdseg",
  #       "comment", "y", "y", "n", "n", "n"],
  #    ["John", "Smith", "john@smith.com", "dfsgfsdgsd",
  #       "comment", "y", "y", "n", "n", "n"],
  #    ["Peter", "Ross", "null", "adfgehs",
  #       "comment", "y", "y", "n", "n", "n"]]
```

Lastly, sort, if desired:

```
arr.sort
```

which produces the result shown in the example above.

Comment: Nice concise answer. Minor change: I think OP wants to compare `e[3]` rather than `e[2]`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Rly good, but he write this. "It's actually the opposite of your result that I want. # => [["John", "Smith", "null", "null", "null", "y", "y", "n", "n", "n"]] should be removed and the others should remain." And your answer dont remove this result.

Comment: @LukasBaliak well the condition was checked for == "null" instead if we check for != "null" we get what OP requires...

Comment: @VamsiKrishna, I expect you are correct. In fact, you can see from the edit history that my original answer was the same as your edit. I changed it after rereading the last sentence of the question.